# Scroll not happening after frame layout zooming in android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Scroll not working after `FrameLayout` zooming in Android. I will try to zoom the `FrameLayout`  , after that zooming I want to scroll the `FrameLayout` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: @Scott Nova gave me an easy library solution using [GestureFrameLayout](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews/wiki/Usage) from this library!

And [this](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews) is GestureView.

Add the dependency into your Gradle file.

```
 compile 'com.alexvasilkov:gesture-views:2.3.2'
```

Comment: how to download this library?@Dennis

Comment: Selected `Code` on top of header...then click clone or download